# React MapBox GL geocoder input outside the map is that possible?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I have a React app and in search screen I have multiple options of filtering and also I want to put the address input. In the result page will show the map with the starting and destination points but this will be received as props from the previews page. Now from what I could see you can add the geocoding only inside the map but I am wondered if any of you faced this question and found an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

react-map-gl-geocoder place outside of the map example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v0m14q5rly?file=/src/index.js

```
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import "react-map-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MapGL from "react-map-gl";
import DeckGL, { GeoJsonLayer } from "deck.gl";
import Geocoder from "react-map-gl-geocoder";


const MAPBOX_TOKEN =  "<YOUR MAPBOX API TOKEN>";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      latitude: 37.7577,
      longitude: -122.4376,
      zoom: 8
    },
    searchResultLayer: null
  };

  mapRef = React.createRef();
  geocoderContainerRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize);
    this.resize();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize);
  }

  resize = () => {
    this.handleViewportChange({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    });
  };

  handleViewportChange = viewport => {
    this.setState({
      viewport: { ...this.state.viewport, ...viewport }
    });
  };

  // if you are happy with Geocoder default settings, you can just use handleViewportChange directly
  handleGeocoderViewportChange = viewport => {
    const geocoderDefaultOverrides = { transitionDuration: 1000 };

    return this.handleViewportChange({
      ...viewport,
      ...geocoderDefaultOverrides
    });
  };

  handleOnResult = event => {
    this.setState({
      searchResultLayer: new GeoJsonLayer({
        id: "search-result",
        data: event.result.geometry,
        getFillColor: [255, 0, 0, 128],
        getRadius: 1000,
        pointRadiusMinPixels: 10,
        pointRadiusMaxPixels: 10
      })
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { viewport, searchResultLayer } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          ref={this.geocoderContainerRef}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            background: "black",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            paddingLeft: 4
          }}
        />
        <MapGL
          ref={this.mapRef}
          {...viewport}
          onViewportChange={this.handleViewportChange}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        >
          <Geocoder
            mapRef={this.mapRef}
            containerRef={this.geocoderContainerRef}
            onResult={this.handleOnResult}
            onViewportChange={this.handleGeocoderViewportChange}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
          />
          <DeckGL {...viewport} layers={[searchResultLayer]} />
        </MapGL>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Official example and a related GitHub issue:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-outside-the-map/

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7877

Comment: This example is not in the context of a react app and adapting this html example to a react app is not obvious.